# Errors from a bash script run from cron

Tags: bash-scripting

My rsync cron job does not run at the expected time and below are my scripts.
It gives me the error:

> crond[9231]: unable to create mail file /var/spool/cron/cron.YSwg8Z/cron.root.9290: cron output for user root /usr/bin/run-parts /etc/cron.hourly 1> /dev/null to /dev/null

Cron:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "START NOW ......"
DOMAINS=""

BIGDOMAINS=""

mailadmin=""
sysemail="mailsync_script@xxx.xx.xx"
Date=$(date)
start_date=`date +"%d-%m-%Y %r"`
for domain in $DOMAINS; do
    rsync -arv --delete /data1/popmail/$domain/ -e ssh root@xxx.xx.xx.xx:/data/popmail/$domain/
done
sleep 10
for bigdomain in $BIGDOMAINS; do
    rsync -arv --delete /data1/popmail/$bigdomain/ -e ssh root@xxx.xx.xx.xx:/data/popmail/$bigdomain/
end_date=`date +"%d-%m-%Y %r"`
echo "Backup for all Email Domains Started at $start_date and Completed at $end_date. " | mailx -r $sysemail -s "Backup Successful on $Date" $mailadmin
```

> Error :/usr/local/scripts/WSdomainsrsync: line 20: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Could somebody help out on this

Answer (score 1):

There's no `done` to close that second (bigdomain) `for` loop.

I'm guessing you meant to place the `done` after the `rsync` command.

```
for bigdomain in $BIGDOMAINS; do
    rsync -arv --delete /data1/popmail/$bigdomain/ -e ssh root@xxx.xx.xx.xx:/data/popmail/$bigdomain/
done
```